# Build Python2.7.10 in visual studio 2015 error

Tags: python-2.7, build, module, visual-studio-2005

I want to compile python27.lib
I tried with visual studio 2015. and i get this error
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line

```
Error   C2065   'timezone': undeclared identifier   pythoncore  C:\Users\Ira\Downloads\Python-2.7.10\Modules\timemodule.c   713
```

http://prntscr.com/98ngp6

I think it's from some includes that was changed in 2015...

Comment: please add some code snippet so, that it makes more sense and also, add error messages as text.

Comment: As of today, it's still broken.

Comment: You got this solution. I am trying to do the same, build python 2.7.15 with VS2015.